# How use joinBy with subregion in France with HighMaps?

Tags: highcharts, highmaps

I'm trying to update this example for HighMaps :

```js
// Prepare demo data
// Data is joined to map using value of 'hc-key' property by default.
// See API docs for 'joinBy' for more info on linking data and map.
var data = [
    ['fr-e-mb', 0],
    ['fr-r-vd', 1],
    ['fr-k-ad', 2],
    ['fr-u-vc', 3],
    ['fr-g-hm', 4],
    ['fr-g-mr', 5],
    ['fr-o-no', 6],
    ['fr-n-hp', 7],
    ['fr-f-in', 8],
    ['fr-t-vn', 9],
    ['fr-b-dd', 10],
    ['fr-t-cm', 11],
    ['fr-u-am', 12],
    ['fr-u-vr', 13],
    ['fr-u-ap', 14],
    ['fr-v-ai', 15],
    ['fr-s-as', 16],
    ['fr-u-bd', 17],
    ['fr-n-av', 18],
    ['fr-k-ga', 19],
    ['fr-g-ab', 20],
    ['fr-d-co', 21],
    ['fr-d-sl', 22],
    ['fr-f-ch', 23],
    ['fr-l-cr', 24],
    ['fr-r-ml', 25],
    ['fr-t-ds', 26],
    ['fr-t-ct', 27],
    ['fr-v-dm', 28],
    ['fr-v-ah', 29],
    ['fr-q-eu', 30],
    ['fr-j-es', 31],
    ['fr-f-el', 32],
    ['fr-n-hg', 33],
    ['fr-j-hd', 34],
    ['fr-l-hv', 35],
    ['fr-r-st', 36],
    ['fr-f-il', 37],
    ['fr-v-is', 38],
    ['fr-i-ju', 39],
    ['fr-i-hn', 40],
    ['fr-v-lr', 41],
    ['fr-n-tg', 42],
    ['fr-n-lo', 43],
    ['fr-b-lg', 44],
    ['fr-k-lz', 45],
    ['fr-e-iv', 46],
    ['fr-m-mm', 47],
    ['fr-m-ms', 48],
    ['fr-d-ni', 49],
    ['fr-l-cz', 50],
    ['fr-c-pd', 51],
    ['fr-n-ge', 52],
    ['fr-b-pa', 53],
    ['fr-v-sv', 54],
    ['fr-j-se', 55],
    ['fr-j-vp', 56],
    ['fr-j-ss', 57],
    ['fr-j-vm', 58],
    ['fr-s-so', 59],
    ['fr-i-tb', 60],
    ['fr-i-db', 61],
    ['fr-j-vo', 62],
    ['fr-m-vg', 63],
    ['fr-j-yv', 64],
    ['fr-f-lc', 65],
    ['fr-h-cs', 66],
    ['fr-e-fi', 67],
    ['fr-h-hc', 68],
    ['fr-p-mh', 69],
    ['fr-g-an', 70],
    ['fr-n-ag', 71],
    ['fr-a-br', 72],
    ['fr-p-cv', 73],
    ['fr-c-cl', 74],
    ['fr-e-ca', 75],
    ['fr-b-gi', 76],
    ['fr-a-hr', 77],
    ['fr-v-hs', 78],
    ['fr-k-he', 79],
    ['fr-b-ld', 80],
    ['fr-r-la', 81],
    ['fr-m-mo', 82],
    ['fr-p-or', 83],
    ['fr-o-pc', 84],
    ['fr-k-po', 85],
    ['fr-r-my', 86],
    ['fr-q-sm', 87],
    ['fr-d-yo', 88],
    ['fr-c-al', 89],
    ['fr-c-hl', 90],
    ['fr-u-ha', 91],
    ['fr-f-lt', 92],
    ['fr-s-oi', 93],
    ['fr-v-rh', 94],
    ['fr-n-ta', 95],
    ['undefined', 96],
    ['fr-re-re', 97],
    ['fr-yt-yt', 98],
    ['fr-gf-gf', 99],
    ['fr-mq-mq', 100],
    ['fr-gp-gp', 101],
    ['undefined', 102]
];

// Create the chart
Highcharts.mapChart('container', {
    chart: {
        map: 'countries/fr/fr-all-all'
    },

    title: {
        text: 'Highmaps basic demo'
    },

    subtitle: {
        text: 'Source map: <a href="http://code.highcharts.com/mapdata/countries/fr/fr-all-all.js">France, admin2</a>'
    },

    mapNavigation: {
        enabled: true,
        buttonOptions: {
            verticalAlign: 'bottom'
        }
    },

    colorAxis: {
        min: 0
    },

    series: [{
        data: data,
        name: 'Random data',
        states: {
            hover: {
                color: '#BADA55'
            }
        },
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            format: '{point.name}'
        }
    }, {
            name: 'Separators',
            type: 'mapline',
            data: Highcharts.geojson(Highcharts.maps['countries/fr/fr-all-all'], 'mapline'),
            color: 'silver',
            showInLegend: false,
            enableMouseTracking: false
        }]
});
```

```css
#container {
    height: 500px; 
    min-width: 310px; 
    max-width: 800px; 
    margin: 0 auto; 
}
.loading {
    margin-top: 10em;
    text-align: center;
    color: gray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/maps/highmaps.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/maps/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/mapdata/countries/fr/fr-all-all.js"></script>

<div id="container"></div>
```

Into my purpose:

```js
// Prepare demo data
// Data is joined to map using value of 'hc-key' property by default.
// See API docs for 'joinBy' for more info on linking data and map.
var data = [
    ['Bas-Rhin', 1000]
];

// Create the chart
Highcharts.mapChart('container', {
    chart: {
        map: 'countries/fr/fr-all-all'
    },

    title: {
        text: 'Highmaps basic demo'
    },

    subtitle: {
        text: 'Source map: <a href="http://code.highcharts.com/mapdata/countries/fr/fr-all-all.js">France, admin2</a>'
    },

    mapNavigation: {
        enabled: true,
        buttonOptions: {
            verticalAlign: 'bottom'
        }
    },

    colorAxis: {
        min: 0
    },

    series: [{
        data: data,
        joinBy: 'name',
        name: 'Random data',
        states: {
            hover: {
                color: '#BADA55'
            }
        },
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            format: '{point.name}'
        }
    }]
});
```

```css
#container {
    height: 500px; 
    min-width: 310px; 
    max-width: 800px; 
    margin: 0 auto; 
}
.loading {
    margin-top: 10em;
    text-align: center;
    color: gray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/maps/highmaps.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/maps/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/mapdata/countries/fr/fr-all-all.js"></script>

<div id="container"></div>
```

I would like to join the data with the name of french department.

I don't get the trouble. I saw other example like this one http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/maps/accessibility/accessible-map/ or according to the offical document, we can use other parameter to join our data and the HighMaps mapdata.

A also try with this json object for data but it didn't work neither :

```
[{"dpt":"Bas-Rhin", "value":"1000"}]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the `joinBy` you need to declare the mapping fields. Replace your data with array of objects, define a name and combine with name in a source file.

```
joinBy: ['name', 'code'],
```

Example:

- http://jsfiddle.net/5ejzk2w7

Comment: In your data object you have name like 'fr-e-mb' which is hc-key field in a https://code.highcharts.com/mapdata/countries/fr/fr-all-all.js. Im a little bit confused.

Comment: The first example is from HighMaps official documentation. I used it to build the second example which represent what I'm looking for.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. In the joinBy you need to declare the mapping fields. Replace your data with array of objects, define a name and combine with name in a source file. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/5ejzk2w7/ Let me know if it is correct with your expecations

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly my purpose :) ! (if you edit your answer with this, I will mark it as the solution)

Comment: @KevinB I did that ;)