# Join regions highmaps

Tags: javascript, highcharts

What I want to accomplish is to join/merge two or more regions in Highmaps. E.g. say you want to show the population for Europe + Asia, then when you hoover Asia or Europe they appear as one connected region with the acumulated population

I tried the following, but with no success:

```
var data = [
[['eu', 'as'], 0],
['af', 2],
['na', 4],
['sa', 5]];
```

With the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/2ek3mp1s/3/

Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe this could help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44715083/how-use-joinby-with-subregion-in-france-with-highmaps

Comment: Unfortunately not. Perhaps there exist no such feature in Highcharts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course, one option is to change the underlying geo data. But if you don't want to do that, you can tweak the `mouseOver` event so that it highlights at the same time the countries with the same value.

Here's a demo:

```js
// Prepare demo data
// Data is joined to map using value of 'hc-key' property by default.
// See API docs for 'joinBy' for more info on linking data and map.
var data = [
  ['eu', 0],
  ['as', 0],
  ['af', 2],
  ['na', 4],
  ['sa', 5]
];

// Create the chart
Highcharts.mapChart('container', {
  chart: {
    map: 'custom/world-continents'
  },

  title: {
    text: 'Highmaps basic demo'
  },

  plotOptions: {
    map: {
      point: {
        events: {
          mouseOver: function() {
            var v = this.value
            Highcharts.each(this.series.points, function(p) {
              if (v == p.value) {
                p.setState('hover')
              }
            });
          },
          mouseOut: function() {
            Highcharts.each(this.series.points, function(p) {
              p.setState('')
            });
          }
        }
      },
      allAreas: false,
    }
  },
  subtitle: {
    text: 'Source map: <a href="http://code.highcharts.com/mapdata/custom/world-continents.js">World continents</a>'
  },

  mapNavigation: {
    enabled: true,
    buttonOptions: {
      verticalAlign: 'bottom'
    }
  },

  colorAxis: {
    min: 0
  },

  series: [{
    data: data,
    name: 'Random data',
    states: {
      hover: {
        color: '#BADA55'
      }
    },
    dataLabels: {
      enabled: true,
      format: '{point.name}'
    }
  }]
})
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/maps/highmaps.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/maps/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/mapdata/custom/world-continents.js"></script>

<div id="container"></div>
```

Jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/user2314737/uhp2wgkn/

See also Highcharts ["Categorized areas" demo](https://www.highcharts.com/maps/demo/category-map)

Answer (score 0):

Not solving my exact issue, but found a way to achieve similar for Europe. In this case I connect Sweden and Finland(`"name": "path7025"`):

http://jsfiddle.net/huqfkc2y/

by adding their respective region. Case dismissed.